# How can you change a JSON value in a command in discord.py in a simple way?

Tags: json, discord.py

What I'm trying to do:
First, when the user runs the command +enter {item}, I check if {item} is a value in the json file.  If it is, I want to change the value that corresponds to {item}. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
@bot.command()
async def enter(ctx, item=None):
  ID2 = await get_OneDaySlots_data()

  if item != None and str(item) in str(ID2["Slot List"].values()):
    #your answer here
      
  if item not in str(ID2["Slot List"].values()):
    await ctx.send("Item ID not in Item ID List.")

  with open('OneDaySlots.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(ID2, f)
```

If you need any clarification **please** ask me in comments. Thanks!

note: my prefix is '+' and My JSON File looks like this:

```
{"Slot List": {"Slot1": 0, "Slot2": 0, "Slot3": 0, "Slot4": 0, "Slot5": 0, "Slot6": 0, "Slot7": 0, "Slot8": 0, "Slot9": 0, "Slot10": 0, "Slot11": 0, "Slot12": 0, "Slot13": 0, "Slot14": 0, "Slot15": 0, "Slot16": 0, "Slot17": 0, "Slot18": 0, "Slot19": 0, "Slot20": 0, "Slot21": 0, "Slot22": 0, "Slot23": 0, "Slot24": 0, "Slot25": 0, "Slot26": 0, "Slot27": 0, "Slot28": 0, "Slot29": 0, "Slot30": 0, "Slot31": 0, "Slot32": 0, "Slot33": 0, "Slot34": 0, "Slot35": 0, "Slot36": 0, "Slot37": 0, "Slot38": 0, "Slot39": 0, "Slot40": 0, "Slot41": 0, "Slot42": 0, "Slot43": 0, "Slot44": 0, "Slot45": 0, "Slot46": 0, "Slot47": 0, "Slot48": 0, "Slot49": 0, "Slot50": 0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this maybe. slots being your json/dict

```
key = [k for k, v in slots["Slot List"].items() if v == item][0]

slots["Slot List"][key] = 'your new value'
```